# Run .jar file from java program with arguments

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a jar file from another java program.
Current code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBulder("java", "-Djava=\"libs\\native\\windows\"", "-jar", "example.jar", arg1, arg2, arg3);
pb.directory(new File("my\\directory\\folder"));
Process process = pb.start();
```

When this code is executed i get no error and nothing appears to actually happen.

Comment: Is java on the path?

Comment: Regardless of your actual problem: why don't you append the jar to your classpath and just call the jar's main method?

Comment: Adding the jar to the class path worked out to be a much better way of doing things. I'm a bit of a noob at this so i didn't think of that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With `ProcessBuilder.start()` you start a new thread. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) states:

> By default, the created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process

So, if you don't specifically ask for it, you will never see results from that process (this includes error messages from it's start up).

A way better alternative is not relying on the `ProcessBuilder` at all. If your callee is a JVM class, just include the JAR on your application's classpath like so:

```
java -classpath ./example.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

You're then free to call `example`'s methods:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example.main(new String[] { "bla", "blubb", "blabb" });
    }
}
```